# d3 js - clustering bubbles to segments

Tags: javascript, d3.js

**** LATEST FIDDLE --- https://jsfiddle.net/tk5xog0g/8/

-- 2nd fiddle with a custom chart -- randomly placing the bubbles closer to region zones but can not account for overlapping or falling off the central chart zone. http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1484/

I want to combine a doughtnut pie and a bubble chart to produce an exact result like this

[image]

The closest I have got to - is here.

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/tk5xog0g/10/

```
/* ------- ANIMATE BUBBLES -------*/


// generate data with calculated layout values

var data = bubbledata(data);

var nodes = bubble.nodes(data)
  .filter(function(d) {
    return !d.children;
  }); // filter out the outer bubble


var bubbles = bubs.selectAll('circle')
  .data(nodes);



bubbles.enter()
  .insert("circle")
  .attr('transform', function(d) {
    return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')';
  })
  .attr('r', function(d) {
    return d.r;
  })
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.group);
  });


bubbles = bubbles.transition()
  .transition()
  .duration(250)
  .attr('transform', function(d) {
    return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')';
  })
  .attr('r', function(d) {
    //console.log("dr", d.r)
    return d.r;
  })
  .ease('sine');

/* ------- ANIMATE BUBBLES -------*/
```

I have also looked at trying to cluster the bubble chart to at least always group the colours together -- but this still won't match the required chart -- with the need for the colour bubbles to be close to the matching pie segments.

-- this is a clustered variant but the orange bubbles may sit sandwiched in the middle and once I try and merge it with the pie - won't correspond. I have considered trying to add a charge/gravity to try and get the bubbles to repel.
https://jsfiddle.net/tk5xog0g/20/
[image]

- [D3 Force Layout where larger nodes cluster in center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32274775/d3-force-layout-where-larger-nodes-cluster-in-center)
- [d3 clustered force layout, distance between cluster center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16465719/d3-clustered-force-layout-distance-between-cluster-center)
- [Adding new nodes to a clustered force layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22712913/adding-new-nodes-to-a-clustered-force-layout)
- [d3.js: how to create "force-directed graph clusters"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10731008/d3-js-how-to-create-force-directed-graph-clusters)

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7881887

```js
var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 60)
    .innerRadius(radius - 70);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d.value; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");


  var data = [
    {
      "group": "<5",
      "value": 1000,
      "children": [
        {
          "group": "<5",     
          "label": "Mel",
          "value": 1000,
          "totalGroupValue": 1000
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "group": "5-13",
      "value": 1000,
      "children": [
        {
          "group": "5-13",        
          "label": "Erica",
          "value": 1000,
          "totalGroupValue": 1000
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "group": "14-17",
      "value": 2000,
      "children": [
        {
          "group": "14-17",
          "label": "Jessica",
          "value": 1500,
          "totalGroupValue": 2000  
        },
        {
          "group": "14-17",
          "label": "Jill",
          "value": 500,
          "totalGroupValue": 2000  
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "group": "18-24",
      "value": 1300,
      "children": [
        {
          "group": "18-24",
          "label": "Jerry",
          "value": 500,          
          "totalGroupValue": 1300 
        },
        {
          "group": "18-24",
          "label": "Ben",
          "value": 500,
          "totalGroupValue": 1300  
        },
        {
          "group": "18-24",
          "label": "Billy",
          "value": 300,
          "totalGroupValue": 1300  
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "group": "25-44",
      "value": 1000,
      "children": [
        {
          "group": "25-44",
          "label": "Kelly",
          "value": 1000,
          "totalGroupValue": 1000
        }
      ]
    }
  ];  


  var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(data))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

  g.append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color(d.data.group); 
      });

  arc
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(0);
   

//create zone regions
var zones = [];
g.append("circle")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {

    zones[d.data.group] = arc.centroid(d);
    //zones.push(obj);

    return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; 
  })
  .attr("r", "1px")
  .style("fill", function(d) { 
    return "black"//color(d.data.group); 
  });
//create zone regions


//custom bubble chart
function makeBubbles(transform, group, radius){
    g.append("circle")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate("+transform+")"; 
    })
    .attr("r", radius)
    .style("stroke", function(d) { 
      return "black";//color(group); 
    })
    .style("fill", function(d) { 
      return color(group); 
    });
}

//loop through data and for EACH children array paint dots.
$.each(data, function( index, value ) {

  $.each(value.children, function( i, v ) {
      var randomX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101) - 50;
      var randomY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101) - 50;      

      var zoneregion = zones[v.group];
      var transform = (zoneregion[0] - randomX)+","+(zoneregion[1]+randomY);
      var group = v.group;
      var radius = ((v.value/v.totalGroupValue)*100) *0.5;
      makeBubbles(transform, group, radius);

  });    
});    
//custom bubble chart    
   

function type(d) {
  d.value = +d.value;
  return d;
}
```

```css
.arc text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

.arc path {
  stroke: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<body>
```

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/CslZ0raP7QsEAMcunol4?p=preview -- if there is a way of arranging the bubbles manually towards these pie segment areas? -- Would it right to render the slice/arcs -- then create a "virtual rectangle region" - per segment and then FIND these corresponding bubbles and move them closer to those segments.. my concern though is to avoid collision overlapping?

Comment: http://vallandingham.me/vis/gates/

Comment: http://slodge.com/teach/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22340334/d3-js-user-viewer-chart

Comment: -- so this is the chart -- http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/379/ -- and it remaps the dots -- I suppose the question is a) how do I calculate suitable pie slice regions near the outer edges, but still inside the main circle b) do I "simulate" a future position to avoid overlapping before animating the bubbles to those regions?

Comment: -- I've adapted this custom bubble chart to try and fulfil the needs -- http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1477/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1481/ - tried making a custom bubble chart

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps.

```js
var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 60)
    .innerRadius(radius - 70);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d.population; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var data = [
 {"age":"<5", "population":"2704659"},
{"age":"5-13", "population":"4499890"},
{"age":"14-17", "population":"2159981"},
{"age":"18-24", "population":"3853788"},
{"age":"25-44", "population":"14106543"},
{"age":"45-64", "population":"8819342"},
{"age":"≥65", "population":"612463"}
];

  var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(data))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

  g.append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.age); });

  arc
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(0);
   
  g.append("circle")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
      .attr("r", "15px")
   .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.age); });

function type(d) {
  d.population = +d.population;
  return d;
}
```

```css
.arc text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

.arc path {
  stroke: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: can it handle multiple bubbles per segment?

Comment: another issue is animating it

Comment: what exactly do you want ? what additional features are to be added to the current state ?

Comment: -- I will try and look at the code you have here.. --- essentially there could be multiple bubbles per pie chart slice -- so a more granualar representation of a slice -- and then of course when new data is appended the slices will tween -- and the bubbles will grow/shrink in size or pop/out-in to existence accordingly

Comment: add the additional features required, I will try if I can achieve that

Comment: ^ I've refactored the data json -- so the pie chart is powered by the parent

Comment: the goal is to have the bubbles powered by the children array of EACH parent

Comment: -- want it to look a little like this -- but have the bubbles gravitate toward their corresponding segments -- http://i.stack.imgur.com/lreKr.png

Comment: 1) putting multiple dots/bubbles of different radius's inside a segment quadrant... 2) animating all this so its feels fluid  -- ** this is as close as I have got -- https://jsfiddle.net/tk5xog0g/8/

Comment: ---if you could get the animation and style -- with the randomize button in place -- with this chart -- then its getting there -- https://jsfiddle.net/tk5xog0g/8/

Comment: ---there is an algorithm that could be used too keep the bubbles inside the circumference -- http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1478/

Comment: ****UPDATE -- using your arccentroid dots as placeholders -- I've made svg bubblechart holders and now PINNED each child unit to those holders -- http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1487/

Comment: @dragon-slayer could you help me update the fiddle to now animate the chart -- arcs, bubbles, put back the two sets of dummy data to test ---- http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1496/

Comment: --- I've tried to add back the randomizing of data and animating the arcs -- but its just tearing -- http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1502/

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Latest fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1505/

( http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1506/ )- refactored

```
 1. -- how to animate the arcs
 2. -- how to animate the bubbles
 3. -- adding back the randomise button to test with 2 dummy data sets.
```

---

this is the old pie animations and worked very well

```
                /* ------- ANIMATE PIE SLICES -------*/
                var slice = doughpie.select(".slices").selectAll("path.slice")
                  .data(pie(data), key);

                slice.enter()
                  .insert("path")
                  .style("fill", function(d) {
                    return color(d.data.label);
                  })
                  .style("transform", function(d, i){
                    //return "translate(0, 0)";
                  })
                  .attr("class", "slice");

                slice
                  .transition().duration(1000)
                  .attrTween("d", function(d) {
                    this._current = this._current || d;
                    var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
                    this._current = interpolate(0);
                    return function(t) {
                      return arc(interpolate(t));
                    };
                  })

                slice.exit()
                  .remove();
                /* ------- ANIMATE PIE SLICES -------*/
```

//this is the current pie arcs - but when I try and animate the pie in the same manner - it fails.

```
var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
  .data(pie(data))
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "arc");

g.append("path")
  .attr("d", arc)
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.data.label);
  });

arc
  .outerRadius(radius - 10)
  .innerRadius(0);
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1505/  -- I've tried to add some randomizng button ready to try and take on animations

Comment: I need help animating it though

Comment: -- why can't I get the arcs to tween again -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39190623/d3-refactored-pie-chart-animations-failing